# Why I can't filter vertices from graph using subgraph by custom properties?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, filtering

I wanted to have a way to filter the graph using vertices and edges custom properties in Mathematica 11.1. But this code doesn't work the way I expected:

```
g = GridGraph[{25, 50}];
PropertyValue[{g, #}, "myprop"] = "myval"; & /@ Range[0, 1250, 7];
f = ! PropertyValue[{g, #}, "myprop"] === "myval" &;
sg2 = Subgraph[g, _?f]
Sort[VertexList[sg2]] == Select[Range[25*50], Mod[#, 7] != 0 &]
```

It returns `False` and the graph looks like this:
[image]

Interestingly if I run:

```
VertexList[sg2]
```

I see that the vertices that should be removed are in the end of the list. So somehow `Subgraph` processed them, but didn't remove.

On the other hand if I use this code, where I remove every 7th vertex by its id:

```
g = GridGraph[{25, 50}];
sg = Subgraph[g, _?(Mod[#, 7] != 0 &)]
Sort[VertexList[sg]] == Select[Range[25*50], Mod[#, 7] != 0 &]
```

The result is `True` and the graph looks like this:
[image]

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Property handling is [unfortunately](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1061356) [terribly](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1060163) [buggy](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1060237).  But this is **not** a bug.  It's your function `f` returning `True` for all edges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a bug.

From the documentation:

> `Subgraph[g,patt]` gives the subgraph generated by the vertices **and edges** that match the pattern `patt`.

Your function `f` is returning `True` for all edges.  Use

```
f = VertexQ[g, #] && PropertyValue[{g, #}, "myprop"] =!= "myval" &;
```